# Symfony 3.4 - SonataUser - Twig - Blank Page

Tags: sonata-admin, symfony-3.4, sonata-user-bundle

I have a problem for 2 days, I'm new in Symfony.

I'm using Symfony 3.4.

I create a Backend with Sonata for manage Entities and User.
My backend is ok, but now the twig templates are no longer working. I just have blank page. 
Can you help me ? Thanks you in advance.

Here is my files :

composer.json

```
{
"name": "renicom.com/rcmanager1",
"license": "proprietary",
"type": "project",
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "AppBundle\\": "src/AppBundle",
        "Application\\": "src/Application"
    },
    "classmap": [
        "app/AppKernel.php",
        "app/AppCache.php"
    ]
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Tests\\": "tests/"
    },
    "files": [
        "vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/VarDumper/Resources/functions/dump.php"
    ]
},
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.5.9",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^1.6",
    "doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "^1.3",
    "doctrine/orm": "^2.5",
    "friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle": "^2.3",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "^2.0",
    "knplabs/knp-markdown-bundle": "^1.7",
    "knplabs/knp-paginator-bundle": "^2.8",
    "nelmio/api-doc-bundle": "^3.2",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "^5.0.19",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^5.0.0",
    "sonata-project/admin-bundle": "^3.35",
    "sonata-project/block-bundle": "^3.12",
    "sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle": "^3.6",
    "sonata-project/easy-extends-bundle": "^2.5",
    "sonata-project/google-authenticator": "^2.1",
    "sonata-project/intl-bundle": "^2.5",
    "sonata-project/media-bundle": "^3.13",
    "sonata-project/user-bundle": "^4.2",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.1.0",
    "symfony/polyfill-apcu": "^1.0",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "^2.6.4",
    "symfony/symfony": "3.4.*",
    "symfony/templating": "^4.1",
    "twig/twig": "^1.0||^2.0"
},
"require-dev": {
    "sensio/generator-bundle": "^3.0",
    "symfony/phpunit-bridge": "^3.0"
},
"scripts": {
    "symfony-scripts": [
        "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::prepareDeploymentTarget"
    ],
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "@symfony-scripts"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "@symfony-scripts"
    ]
},
"config": {
    "sort-packages": true
},
"extra": {
    "symfony-app-dir": "app",
    "symfony-bin-dir": "bin",
    "symfony-var-dir": "var",
    "symfony-web-dir": "web",
    "symfony-tests-dir": "tests",
    "symfony-assets-install": "relative",
    "incenteev-parameters": {
        "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
    },
    "branch-alias": null
}
```

}

AppKernel.php

```
$bundles = [
        new Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\SecurityBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\MonologBundle\MonologBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\SwiftmailerBundle(),
        new Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DoctrineBundle(),
        new Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\SensioFrameworkExtraBundle(),
        new AppBundle\AppBundle(),
        new Doctrine\Bundle\MigrationsBundle\DoctrineMigrationsBundle(),

        new Sonata\CoreBundle\SonataCoreBundle(),
        new Sonata\BlockBundle\SonataBlockBundle(),
        new Knp\Bundle\MenuBundle\KnpMenuBundle(),
        new Sonata\DoctrineORMAdminBundle\SonataDoctrineORMAdminBundle(),

        new Sonata\AdminBundle\SonataAdminBundle(),

        new Sonata\EasyExtendsBundle\SonataEasyExtendsBundle(),

        new FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserBundle(),
        new Sonata\UserBundle\SonataUserBundle('FOSUserBundle'),
        new Application\Sonata\UserBundle\ApplicationSonataUserBundle(),

        new Sonata\MediaBundle\SonataMediaBundle(),
        new Application\Sonata\MediaBundle\ApplicationSonataMediaBundle(),
        new JMS\SerializerBundle\JMSSerializerBundle(),

        new Sonata\IntlBundle\SonataIntlBundle(),

        new Knp\Bundle\MarkdownBundle\KnpMarkdownBundle(),

        new Knp\Bundle\PaginatorBundle\KnpPaginatorBundle(),

    ];
```

The Controller

```
    <?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;


use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;


class AssetController extends Controller
{


    /**
     * @Route("/objets", name="asset_list_fr")
     */
    public function listAction(Request $request, $slug = 'test'){

        $asset_list = array();
        if ($request->isMethod('GET')){
            $params = $request->query;

            $category = $this->getDoctrine()
                ->getRepository('AppBundle:Category');
            $categoryP = $category->findOneBy(array('id'    =>  4));

            $type = $this->getDoctrine()
                ->getRepository('AppBundle:Type');
            $typeP = $type->findOneBy(array('id'    =>  30));

            $sector = $this->getDoctrine()
                ->getRepository('AppBundle:Sector');
            $sectorP = null;//$sector->findOneBy(array('id'   =>  '3'));

            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

            $asset_list = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Asset')
                ->findBy(['category'    =>  $categoryP]);

            $assets = $this->get('knp_paginator')->paginate(
                $asset_list, 1
            );

        }

        return $this->render('asset/list.html.twig',
            [
                'slug'  =>  $slug,
                'assets'    =>  $assets,
            ]);

    }

}
```

My view asset/list.html.twig

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block content %}
 test

{% endblock %}
```

my config.yml

```
imports:
- { resource: parameters.yml }
- { resource: security.yml }
- { resource: services.yml }

parameters:
    locale: en

framework:
    translator: { fallbacks: ['%locale%'] }
    secret: '%secret%'
    router:
        resource: '%kernel.project_dir%/app/config/routing.yml'
        strict_requirements: ~
    form: ~
    csrf_protection: ~
    validation: { enable_annotations: true }
    default_locale: '%locale%'
    trusted_hosts: ~
    session:
        handler_id: session.handler.native_file
        save_path: '%kernel.project_dir%/var/sessions/%kernel.environment%'
    fragments: ~
    http_method_override: true
    assets: ~
    php_errors:
        log: true

twig:
    debug: '%kernel.debug%'
    strict_variables: '%kernel.debug%'

doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver: pdo_mysql
        host: '%database_host%'
        port: '%database_port%'
        dbname: '%database_name%'
        user: '%database_user%'
        password: '%database_password%'
        charset: UTF8
        types:
            json: Sonata\Doctrine\Types\JsonType

    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: '%kernel.debug%'
        entity_managers:
            default:
                auto_mapping: true
                mappings:
                    ApplicationSonataUserBundle: ~
                    SonataUserBundle: ~
                    FOSUserBundle: ~
                    ApplicationSonataMediaBundle: ~
                    SonataMediaBundle: ~


swiftmailer:
    transport: '%mailer_transport%'
    host: '%mailer_host%'
    username: '%mailer_user%'
    password: '%mailer_password%'
    spool: { type: memory }


fos_user:
    db_driver:      orm # can be orm or odm
    firewall_name:  main
    user_class:     Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User 

    group:
        group_class: Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\Group         
        group_manager: sonata.user.orm.group_manager 

    service:
        mailer: fos_user.mailer.twig_swift
        user_manager: sonata.user.orm.user_manager

    from_email:
        address: "test1@test.com" #"%mailer_user%"
        sender_name: "test1@test.com" #"%mailer_user%"

sonata_user:
    security_acl: true
    manager_type: orm
    class:
        user: Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User
        group: Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\Group
    admin:
        user:
            class: Sonata\UserBundle\Admin\Entity\UserAdmin
            controller: SonataAdminBundle:CRUD
            translation: SonataUserBundle
        group:
            class: Sonata\UserBundle\Admin\Entity\GroupAdmin
            controller: SonataAdminBundle:CRUD
            translation: SonataUserBundle

sonata_block:
    default_contexts: [cms]
    blocks:
        sonata.user.block.account:
        sonata.admin.block.admin_list:
            contexts: [admin]

sonata_admin:
    title_logo : /images/logo_remicom.png
    title: Remicom Admin


sonata_media:
    db_driver: doctrine_orm
    default_context: default
    contexts:
        default:
            providers:
                - sonata.media.provider.dailymotion
                - sonata.media.provider.youtube
                - sonata.media.provider.image
                - sonata.media.provider.file
                - sonata.media.provider.vimeo
            formats:
                small: { width: 100, quality: 70}
                big: { width: 500, quality: 70}
    cdn:
        server:
            path: /uploads/media
    filesystem:
        local:
            directory: "%kernel.root_dir%/../public/uploads/media"
            create: false
    providers:
        image:
            resizer: sonata.media.resizer.square

sonata_intl:
    timezone:
        default: Europe/Paris

knp_paginator:
    page_range: 30
```

My routing.yml

```
app:
    resource: '@AppBundle/Controller/'
    type: annotation

admin_area:
    resource: '@SonataAdminBundle/Resources/config/routing/sonata_admin.xml'
    prefix: /admin

_sonata_admin:
    resource: .
    type: sonata_admin
    prefix: /admin

fos_user:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/all.xml"

sonata_user_admin_security:
    resource: '@SonataUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/admin_security.xml'
    prefix: /admin

sonata_user_admin_resetting:
    resource: '@SonataUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/admin_resetting.xml'
    prefix: /admin/resetting
```

I add here 2 screen from the debug section.
[The twig debug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3Ous.png)

[The log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7z732.png)

Answer (score 0):

finaly I solve the problem. I start a new project and rebuild every part of my Symfony application in the same way, and all work well.
I don't know what was the problem. I certainly forget a little thing but I can't say what.